# How to select specific date format in column

Tags: python, pandas, date, jupyter-notebook

I have this data set which have 3 rows. 2nd column is date column which have date in two different format. How can i select date of particular format to display that particular row. i mean there are more rows which have different date format. how can i select all the rows with date format year/date/month and then after selecting all these rows of this format year/date/month and then change to that year/month/date format . Main problem in selecting of particular format

```
     Country      date
18  Australia   2020-01-18  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   44648.71    25499881.0  2020-03-24
19  Australia   2020-19-01  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   44648.71    25499881.0  2020-03-24
20  Australia   2020-01-20  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   44648.71    25499881.0  2020-03-24
```

Comment: How would you know whether `2020-01-02` is year-day-month or year-month-day?

Comment: This happens to me as I am on a USA computer, but deal with UK/European formats. What has worked for me is to specify the format when I `read` in the data, not after. And, if the source file is already like that, then if in .csv format, don't open the file and save it, but save it directly to a folder from whatever system you get it from and read in directly specifying the format.

Comment: beacuse dates are continous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this option (not very elegant):

**Dataset:**

```
Country,date
Australia,2020-01-18
Australia,2020-19-01
Australia,2020-01-20
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df = df.astype('str')
df['date'] = np.where(df['date'].str[5:7].astype('int') > 12
                    , df['date'].str[0:4] + df['date'].str[7:11] + df['date'].str[4:7]
                    , df['date'])

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Country        date
0  Australia  2020-01-18
1  Australia  2020-01-19
2  Australia  2020-01-20
```